# Automatic FTP synchronization with PhpStorm

Tags: php, sftp, phpstorm

I'm trying out PHPStorm by Jetbrains at the moment, which I think is an awesome IDE.

The only complain I have is that Im always in fear that I will overwrite changes other people made.

I'm currently working on a project without Git, just pure FTP. If I start PHPstorm, the first thing I have to do is synchronize my local files manually using the "Compare with local version..." dialog, which takes a lot of time at bigger projects.

Is it possible that PhpStorm behaves like Eclipse Remote Explorer?
It would be awesome if PhpStorm would check the file I just opened for a newer version on my default remote and replaces it automatically.

Comment: Or you could use git.

Comment: Try to avoid FTP and use SFTP if you can. It's still not as good as Git/SSH but at least it is more secure than FTP. Most servers that support FTP will support the secure version too.

Comment: "[I'm] always in fear that I will overwrite changes other people made" - which is where version control is rather handy.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the Tools > Deployment > Options dialog, you will see the following option:

[image: PHPStorm Options]

Changing these options will allow you to customize how your uploads are pushed and when you're warned about overwriting changes

Comment: Very nice, it even alerts me directly when I enter the file with a nice dialog at the top. Just what I wanted :)